# Selecting distinct entries in mysql based on only one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table (image attached).[image]

I want to select only distinct entries based on permanent_token no. I want a result like this:
[image]

How to select distinct entries based on only one column in mysql?

Comment: I am unable to see attached images

Comment: So which record do you want to return in case there are multiple records with the same permanent_token?

Comment: The record with the oldest entry date and time

Comment: Is date and time 2 columns or one source column? (hopefully one)  & Can you provide a few sample data rows in a reusable format?

Comment: They are actually two columns

Comment: please provide a small sample of data (or create your own sqlfiddle we can work with) it's not solved by the distinct keyword, but by using group by subquery and a then join. working with the sample will demonstrate this. also supply the actual table name too.

Comment: unable to operate sql fiddle. can you help me by taking any values for example, but two same values for permanent_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just an example, you will need to work out the seperated date & time columns as a separate issue.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44a4b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`date` date, `time` time, `permanent_token` varchar(8), `RID` int, `SID` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`date`, `time`, `permanent_token`, `RID`, `SID`)
VALUES
    ('2015-08-04 00:00:00', '12:40:41', 'HPC12334', 12, 34),
    ('2015-08-04 00:00:00', '15:15:15', 'HPC12334', 18, 37),
    ('2015-08-04 00:00:00', '08:09:10', 'ABX2334', 48, 47)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
from table1 as t
inner join (
  select permanent_token, `date` , MIN(`time`) as minTime
  from table1
  group by permanent_token, `date`
  ) as gby on t.permanent_token = gby.permanent_token
          and t.`date` = gby.`date`
          and t.`time` = gby.minTime
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44a4b/1/0)**:

```
|                     date |                      time | permanent_token | RID | SID |
|--------------------------|---------------------------|-----------------|-----|-----|
| August, 04 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1970 12:40:41 |        HPC12334 |  12 |  34 |
| August, 04 2015 00:00:00 | January, 01 1970 08:09:10 |         ABX2334 |  48 |  47 |
```

Comment: hopefully you can see the usefulness of a small sample of (reusable) data when asking your questions

Comment: Thanks. Will take care from now on.! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```
select DISTINCT(permenent_token),othercolumnname from tablename order by permenent_token desc
```

Comment: how `othercolumnname` is going to be aggregated ?

Comment: "select distinct" is a row operation, those parentheses are just ignored.

Comment: select DISTINCT(permanent_token),RID,SID,date_FORMAT(date,'%d %b %y'),TIME_FORMAT(time,'%h:%i %p'),title,message,temp_token,status,priority from complaints;

Comment: yes it does not work because distinct in NOT a function so those parentheses are just ignored .... please provide a small sample of data, the solution is via GROUP BY not "select distinct"

Comment: insert into complaints values(11120059,11116037,date(now()),time(now()), 'First' , 'Very Important',CAST(CONCAT( CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(99999999-100)))
 AS CHAR(50)),'1','0','0');

Answer (score 0):

use Mysql **distinct** keyword

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY permanent_token;
```

explain:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: distinct is NOT a function, the syntax is distinct is an option of select. DISTINCTROW is a synonym for distinct i.e. it operate across the whole row not just on the first column, or on columns contained within parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT(coloumn_name) from tablename";
```